# Objective-C, protocols and subclasses

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, protocols, compiler-warnings

Let's say that I have the following protocols defined:

// basic protocol for an User Interface object:

```
@protocol UIObjectProtocol <NSObject>
@property (assign) BOOL touchable;
@end
```

// basic protocol for an User Interface object that is held by a `holder` object:

```
@protocol UIHeldObjectProtocol <UIObjectProtocol>
@property (readonly) id holder;
@end
```

And the following class hierarchy:

// base class for an User Interface object, which synthesizes the `touchable` property

```
@interface UIObject : NSObject <UIObjectProtocol> {
   BOOL _touchable;
}
@end

@implementation UIObject
@synthesize touchable=_touchable;
@end
```

At this point, everything is OK. Then I create a `UIObject` subclass named `UIPlayingCard`. Inherently, `UIPlayingCard` conforms to the `UIObjectProtocol` since it's superclass does it too.

Now suppose I want `UIPlayingCard` to conform to `UIHeldObjectProtocol`, so I do the following:

```
@interface UIPlayingCard : UIObject <UIHeldObjectProtocol> {
}
@end

@implementation UIPlayingCard
-(id)holder { return Nil; }
@end
```

Note that the `UIPlayingCard` conforms to `UIHeldObjectProtocol`, which transitively conforms to `UIObjectProtocol`. However I'm getting compiler warnings in the `UIPlayingCard` such that:

> warning: property 'touchable' requires
>   method '-touchable' to be defined -
>   use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a
>   method implementation

which means that the `UIPlayingCard` superclass conformance to the `UIObjectProtocol` wasn't inherited (maybe because the `@synthesize` directive was declared in the `UIObject` implementation scope).

Am I obligated to re-declare the `@synthesize` directive in the `UIPlayingCard` implementation ?

```
@implementation UIPlayingCard
@synthesize touchable=_touchable; // _touchable now must be a protected attribute
-(id)holder { return Nil; }
@end
```

Or there's another way to get rid of the compiler warning? Would it be the result of bad design?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but it's generally not the best idea to use "Apple's" prefixes for your own classes/protocols/constants/whatevers: You never know what big fruit will include in the next release...

Comment: I agree with you danyowdee, in fact I'm not using the 'UI' prefix in my application and I do follow all these good practices listed by you. I just suppressed the real prefix (the company prefix, for instance) here in the post since it has no relation with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just throw in one other way to silence the warning: use `@dynamic`, and the compiler will assume that the implementation will be provided in some other way than in a declaration in the class's implementation (in this case, it's provided by the superclass).

Comment: Summing up: The workaround (do you consider this a workaround or the use of the @dynamic language feature is correct in this case?) is to do the following: 1) In the `UIObject` implementation: `@synthesize touchable=_touchable` 2) In the `UIPlayingCard` implementation: `@dynamic touchable;`. This is the minimal implementation I can do to solve such problem, right?

Comment: I haven't looked into the language definition to determine whether the GCC or CLANG behavior is correct (or if this situation is not addressed or not clear). If GCC is correct or it's not addressed or unclear, I'd call it a normal and appropriate use; if CLANG is correct, I'd call it a workaround. Either way, it's what I would do.

Yes, that is the minimal implementation to silence the warning.

Answer (score 3):

You comment that `_touchable` would then have to be protected, but you did not include an `@private` compiler directive, so `_touchable` is *already* protected.

Clang does not seem to give this warning in this case, so the most straightforward solution:

- Change your compiler from GCC to Clang.

This will have plenty of side-benefits, as well, including much more intelligible error and warning messages.

It is a bug that GCC complains about this. The implementation is in fact inherited, as you can verify with a simple `main` function exercising `UIPlayingCard`'s `touchable` property. So, your second solution:

- Ignore the warning as bogus. If none of your tests are failing, what do you care, anyway?

Comment: Thanks for reminding about the protected property. I'd rather have a solution for this warnings instead of ignoring them (even that they are bogus). I'm using XCode 4 and I found no straightforward way to change the compiler from GCC to Clang. 1) Changing the compiler will avoid such warnings? 2) Do you use the Clang compiler in which versin of Xcode? Thanks for the great information.

Comment: Clang gets more of the Apple love, and has a more modern architecture, so it tends to have better Obj-C support than anything out there. I'm still using the 3-series of Xcode, but I believe you should be able to select the compiler as part of your build scheme. Try searching for compiler, GCC, or "Default compiler", then flipping that setting.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I obligated to re-declare the @synthesize directive in the UIPlayingCard implementation

Although I don't see from your example, *why* you are doing what you are doing:

No, you don't need to re-implement methods that are already implemented in your parent class.

If the compiler warns about these methods not being present, then that is a bug:
As [The Objective C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html) states...

> When a class adopts a protocol, it must implement the required methods the protocol declares, as mentioned earlier. In addition, it must conform to any protocols the adopted protocol incorporates. If an incorporated protocol incorporates still other protocols, the class must also conform to them. A class can conform to an incorporated protocol by either:
>
> - Implementing the methods the protocol declares, or
> - Inheriting from a class that adopts the protocol and implements the methods.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this piece of information. However, it is still not clear for me the final solution. So, "Inheriting from a class that adopts the protocol and implements the methods." means: Even that the `UIObject` class synthesizes the `touchable` property, the `UIPlayingCard` subclass must implement `-(void)setTouchable:(BOOL)touchable {
    [super setTouchable:touchable];
}` and `- (BOOL)touchable {
    return [super touchable];
}` to USE the superclass implementations (not re-implement them) to avoid the compiler warnings? Or there's another solution that I didn't see?

Comment: No: Whenever you create a subclass, it inherits all the functionality provided by its ancestors — hence it _automatically_ conforms to **any protocol** that those ancestors conform to. This is the meaning of the second bullet-point and the reason why I say that this is a bug in whatever version of the compiler you are using: `UIObject : NSObject <UIObjectProtocol>` says that _any_ `UIObject` (including any instance of classes that are derived from it) will provide the methods defined in the protocol and the `@synthesize` fulfills this contract.

Comment: "Or there's another solution that I didn't see?" 1. File a bug with Apple incorporating a sample project. That way, it may be fixed in a future release. 2. Until they fix it, use Anomie's tip to make the compiler shut up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A Protocol is like a contract.  What you are saying is that UIPlayingCard must implement holder and touchable.

When the compiler compiles UIPlaying card, it doesn't see anywhere that `@property (nonatomic) BOOL touchable;` is defined.

you can't add synthesize to playingCard since playingCard doesn't have the touchable ivar.

Change:

```
@protocol UIHeldObjectProtocol <UIObjectProtocol>
```

to

```
@protocol UIHeldObjectProtocol <NSObject>
```

Since UIPlayingCard inherits from UIObject, the protocols don't need to inherit from each other.

Comment: I have verified that, using GCC, adding the `@property` declaration to `UIObject.h` does NOT stop GCC from emitting the warning.

Comment: yup.  my mistake...  I'll fix the answer.

Comment: That is actually wrong: the property is defined in the protocol that `UIObject` conforms to. And since `UIPlayingCard` inherits `UIObject` it automatically conforms to `UIObjectProtocol`.

Comment: Yes, that's the point `UIPlayingCard` inherits from `UIObject` and so automatically conforms to `UIObjectProtocol`. As Jeremy W. Sherman said "The implementation is in fact inherited, as you can verify with a simple main function exercising UIPlayingCard's touchable property.". The problem is that the compiler is showing the unpleasant warnings.